# How to scrape Airbnb properly

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape Airbnb, indeed only three simple bits of  information: description, city and price of each apartment in a country. However it is not working. All the time it appears the  AttributeError: "ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?"

How can I scrape these data properly?
Here is my code:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36', 
    'Accept-Language':'en-GB, en; q=0.5',
    'Referer':'https://google.com',
    'DNT':'1'}
url = 'https://www.airbnb.com.br/s/Italia/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&price_filter_input_type=0&price_filter_num_nights=5&query=Italia&place_id=ChIJA9KNRIL-1BIRb15jJFz1LOI&date_picker_type=calendar&checkin=2023-03-09&checkout=2023-04-09&adults=1&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

features_dict = {}
descp = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "t1jojoys dir dir-ltr"}).get_text()
city = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "nquyp1l s1cjsi4j dir dir-ltr"}).get_text()
price = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "phbjkf1 dir dir-ltr"}).get_text()

features_dict['descrição'] = descp
features_dict['cidade'] = city
features_dict['preço'] = price
```

Well, I erased the ".get_text()" and the above error did not apper anymore, however all my lists of html elements are empty. When I to a brief check to see whether all html classes are there, I discover that the classes which I'm interested they don't appear.

```
class_list = set()
tags = {tag.name for tag in soup.find_all()}
for tag in tags:
    for i in soup.find_all(tag):
        if i.has_attr("class"):
            if len(i['class']) != 0:
                class_list.add(" ".join(i['class']))
classes = list(class_list)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you read the error message? It's pretty clear. It even suggests a solution.

Comment: Hi, Yevhen, thanks, however even when I erase the ".get_text()" it appears an empty list, when, clearly second the html, the classes that I use are full.

Comment: @Bruhlickd on airbnb the data is rendered dynamically(using javascript) you are using `requests` library which cannot handle js. To get the data you can use for example `selenium`